# Pull rethinkdb monitoring data over HTTP

Tags: http, rethinkdb

Is there a way to retrieve the stats from the rethinkdb monitoring tables over HTTP ? http://rethinkdb.com/blog/1.16-release/#monitoring

Comment: Is there a reason you want to interact through it through HTTP instead of the client driver?

Comment: Yes. As I'm only interested in the server stats I don't want to have yet another dependency in my project. Additionally, I'd have to rewrite the LUA driver to work with luvit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to interact with RethinkDB through HTTP, including the 'rethinkdb' database by which you do table monitoring.

You could easily implement this through using one of the drivers to implement an HTTP backend for your database, although I'm not sure how useful/desirable that would be. But ultimately, you'd need to implement this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I believe those stats are only accessible through the query language right now.